# Can't insert spaces into an html input text box

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, input, partial-views

I've never run into this before but I can't insert a space into any of the input text boxes on a form. Works with other forms on the site

I am using MVC3. This particular for is contained in a partial view and is submitted via a Jquery ajax call.

The form can be found on the bottom of this page:

http://tinyhousemarketplace.com/House/Details/1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `jquery.gallerific.js` you have the following code that is preventing you, ***just debugged it***, from entering a <kbd>space</kbd> or any other <kbd>key</kbd> in the following `switch`:

```
/* ... code ... */

    // Setup Keyboard Navigation
    if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation) {
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
            switch(key) {
                case 32: // space
                    gallery.next();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;

/* ... code ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some javascript preventing spaces. I disabled javascript and could enter the space.

I'm digging through, and I "think" it might be your jQuery UI or maybe the Galleriffic script. I'm looking at `keyCode.SPACE` in jQuery UI and possibly the `e.preventDefault()` in galleriffic.

Sorry, I'm not super strong in JS yet, so some others might be able to see what I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this the below line to list events bound to an element:

```
console.dir( jQuery('form').data('events') );
```